# How do I communicate with a Springboot application on an Azure VM machine?

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot, virtual-machine

I have a springboot application running on a Microsoft azure VM machine, which I want to be able to communicate with from the outside world.

When I type in the address to the application in a browser on the VM machine, which in this case is http://localhost:8080/spring, I get the expected reply back.

However, when I try to reach this application from any other device, even when using the public ip address for the virtualmachine, for some reason I cannot access it.

Do anyone of you know what I should do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to export the port that you want to access externally.

You can find a documentation on how to open ports [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal), through the Azure portal.

To summarize from their documentation:

1. Create a Network Security Group (NSG)
2. Select from the newly created NSG, create a new Inbound security rule
3. Select `HTTP`, your port that you desire (in your case `8080`), priority `100`, give it a name.
4. Your final step is to associate your NSG with a subnet or a specific network interface.

Comment: That fixed it for me, thanks a lot! =)                                                           If anyone else ends up having a simmilar problem, I also found that the Ip flow Verifier was a handy tool for testing if the ports were open; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/network-watcher/network-watcher-ip-flow-verify-overview